# PhoneGap Build - Build an Android application?

Tags: android, xml, cordova, phonegap-build

The problem I am encountering is that I want to unable the orientation on the application that is running on my tablet, I only want landscape view.

I have created the application using cordova, then added the platform "Android". Then I moved the config.xml into the www folder with HTML, CSS and JavaScript code and added the code line below inside config.xml.

Then I zip the www folder with config.xml, and used PhoneGap Build, to convert to an Android application.

When I test this on the tablet, the orientation does not work. How can I prevent orientation on the tablet by using config.xml?

[I found the preference here.](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/config_ref_index.md.html#The%20config.xml%20File)

```
<preference name="Orientation" value="landscape" />
```

Config.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.BachelorProject.KPEC" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>ProjectKPEC</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />

    <preference name="Orientation" value="landscape" />

</widget>
```

Comment: Is there a reason for why I get dislike?

Comment: Which version of phonegap you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Preference attribute values are case sensitive I think.
Try:

```
<preference name="orientation" value="landscape"/>
```

Instead of

```
<preference name="Orientation" value="landscape" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem, just built the whole project  and added android platform again, then I moved config.xml inside www folder, and it worked.